# Is the Ruby literal array syntax a method call?

Tags: ruby

Is the Ruby literal array syntax:

```
[1,2,3]
```

A shortcut to:

```
Array[1,2,3]
```

And thus a constructor method call? Or does it do some other low level magic? I was looking specifically at how you can use keywords:

```
[1,2,3, foo: 'bar']
```

And it has the same effects as a method call.

Comment: I think I kind of found the answer at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html. Which seems to indicate that `[]` is equivent to `Array.[]` but still struggling to understand the the C code.

Comment: The keyword thing is kind of a red herring, they are not really 'keywords' - you can always omit the braces around a hash passed as the last argument.

Comment: Its the "last argument" part here that I'm confused about. That implies that it is actually a method call.

Comment: Are you asking if `[1,2,3]` is "shorthand" for `Array[1,2,3]`, where the latter refers to the *core method* [Array::\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D)? As you say, the doc for the latter gives  both forms for creating an array. Let's say they are "equivalent" iff `[*arr] == Array[*arr]` is `true` for every array `arr`. That could only be proved true (for a given version of Ruby) by comparing the codes by which they are implemented. The onus, it seems to me, is to provide an array `arr` which refutes "equivalence", which has not been provided.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think sepp2k answered this pretty nicely. The literal is actually a built-in while `Array.[]` is "real" Ruby method but both just call the C `rb_ary_s_create` function under the covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of `[1, 2, 3]` is built-in - it is not a shortcut for `Array[1, 2, 3]`. You can see this be redefining `Array[]`:

```
def Array.[](*args)
  puts "Array[] called with arguments #{args}"
end

p [1, a: "b"]      # Will print '[1, {:a=>"b"}]'
p Array[1, a: "b"] # Will print 'Array[] called with arguments [1, {:a=>"b"}]' followed by "nil"
```

The way that `foo: "bar"` is handled is simply a consequence of the rule that hash literals can be written without `{}` when used as the last argument in a method call or array literal. It's only interpreted as a keyword argument when calling a method that's defined to take keyword arguments, otherwise it's treated as a hash.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. So the ruby parser expands the hash literal before its passed as an argument to rb_ary_s_create?

Comment: @max Yes, the hash will be created first and will be the last item in the `argv` array passed to `rb_ary_s_create`.